# How to improve SELECT performance joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql, mamp

I have the following mySQL SELECT statement that was working ok on a small data set but died when the volume was increased:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Bookings.BookingId, Bookings.ResortId, Bookings.WeekBeginning, Bookings.DepartDate, Bookings.CancelledDate,Clients.FirstName, Clients.LastName, Clients.Email, Clients.Address1, Clients.City, Clients.State, Clients.CountryId, Clients.ClientType, Countries.Country, BookingAccommodation.AccomId, BookingAccommodation.ShareType, BookingProgram.ProgramId, Programs.ProgramDesc
    FROM Bookings, Clients, BookingProgram, BookingAccommodation, Countries, ClientType, Programs
    WHERE Bookings.BookingId = BookingProgram.BookingId
       AND Bookings.BookingId = BookingAccommodation.BookingId
       AND Bookings.WeekBeginning >= '2016-10-01' 
       AND BookingAccommodation.Nights > 0
       AND Clients.ClientId = Bookings.ClientId
       AND Clients.Email <> ''
       AND Clients.CountryId = Countries.CountryId
       AND Programs.ProgramId = BookingProgram.ProgramId
```

With around 10K records in Bookings and 25K records in each of BookingAccommodation and BookingPrograms the volume isn't huge but the query ran in 950 seconds. I'm running the query in the SQL window of phpAdmin on a local MAMP server.

Splitting it into 3 queries the result comes back in a fraction of a second for each:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Bookings.BookingId, Bookings.ResortId, Bookings.WeekBeginning, Bookings.DepartDate, Bookings.CancelledDate, Clients.FirstName, Clients.LastName, Clients.Email, Clients.Address1, Clients.City, Clients.State, Clients.CountryId, Clients.ClientType, Countries.Country
     FROM Bookings, Clients, Countries, ClientType
    WHERE Bookings.WeekBeginning >= '2016-10-01' 
       AND Clients.ClientId = Bookings.ClientId
       AND Clients.Email <> ''
       AND Clients.CountryId = Countries.CountryId

SELECT DISTINCT Bookings.BookingId, BookingAccommodation.AccomId, BookingAccommodation.ShareType
    FROM Bookings, BookingAccommodation
    WHERE Bookings.BookingId = BookingAccommodation.BookingId
       AND Bookings.WeekBeginning >= '2016-10-01' 
       AND BookingAccommodation.Nights > 0

SELECT DISTINCT Bookings.BookingId, BookingProgram.ProgramId, Programs.ProgramDesc
    FROM Bookings, BookingProgram, Programs
    WHERE Bookings.BookingId = BookingProgram.BookingId
       AND Bookings.WeekBeginning >= '2016-10-01' 
       AND Programs.ProgramId = BookingProgram.ProgramId
```

There are multiple records in BookingAccommodation and BookingProgram for each record in Bookings but I only require one record from each hence the SELECT DISTINCT.

- The primary key on Bookings is BookingId.
- The primary key on BookingAccommodation is BookingId, AccomDate, AccomId
- The primary key on BookingProgram is BookingId, ProgramId, AccomType

I've tried to rewrite the query with joins and sub queries but I'm obviously not doing it right. How can I join these 3 queries back into a single query that will perform well?

Comment: How about indexes? Are all good?

Comment: See **Section2 / What does Show your Schema Mean?** of [What is Sqlfiddle and why should I care?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38899465) to help us to help you. So that is a decent undertaking considering your, say, 10 tables above. Until then expect nothing decent :p

Answer (score 1):

These are the basics of using subqueries instead of joins (MySQL assumed FWIW). Apologies for pseudocode, I thought it important to answer ASAP as this is one of the top hits on this issue I faced just now.

A client makes a booking to go on a cruise ship. The client should also specify their diet (eg. vegetarian, vegan, no soy, etc). We thus have three tables:

Bookings
Booking_Id, Booking_Date, Booking_Time, Client_Id

Clients
Client_Id, Client_Name, Client_Phone, Client_DietId

Diets
Diet_Id, Diet_Name

We now want to present to the concierge a full booking view.

Using "JOINS":

`SELECT Bookings.Booking_Id, Bookings.Booking_Date, Bookings.Booking_Time, Clients.Client_Name, Diets.Diet_Name
FROM Bookings
INNER JOIN Clients
ON Bookings.Client_Id = Clients.Client_Id
INNER JOIN Diets
ON Clients.Client_DietId = Diets.Diet_Id`

Using "SUBQUERIES":

How I think of it is creating "temp tables" in those separate JOINs - of course "temp tables" may or may not be the accurate low-level implementation, etc. but anecdotally subqueries may be faster than huge joins (other threads on this).

I have separate joins I want to do from the above example:

First I need to join the Clients with their Diets, then I join that "table" with Bookings.

Thus I end up with this (note the table (re)naming when referring to the subquery):

`SELECT [RELEVANT FIELDS HERE ETC] 
FROM 
   (SELECT Clients.Client_Id, Clients.Client_Name, Diets.Diet_Name 
   FROM Clients 
   INNER JOIN Diets
   ON Clients.Client_DietId = Diets.Diet_Id) 
   AS ClientDetailsWithDiets
INNER JOIN Bookings
ON Bookings.Booking_Id = ClientDetailsWithDiets.Client_Id`

Now if another table is to be joined say Staff assigned to a particular Booking, then the whole thing above would be nested, and so on eg:

`SELECT [RELEVANT FIELDS HERE ETC] 
FROM
   (SELECT [RELEVANT FIELDS HERE ETC] 
   FROM 
      (SELECT Clients.Client_Id, Clients.Client_Name, Diets.Diet_Name 
      FROM Clients 
      INNER JOIN Diets
      ON Clients.Client_DietId = Diets.Diet_Id)
      AS ClientDetailsWithDiets
   INNER JOIN Bookings
   ON Bookings.Booking_Id = ClientDetailsWithDiets.Client_Id)
   AS BookingDetailsFull
INNER JOIN Staff 
ON BookingDetailsFull.Booking_Id = Staff.Booking_Id_Assigned`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it as

```
SELECT DISTINCT Bookings.BookingId, Bookings.ResortId, 
Bookings.WeekBeginning, Bookings.DepartDate, Bookings.CancelledDate,
Clients.FirstName, Clients.LastName, Clients.Email, Clients.Address1, 
Clients.City, Clients.State, Clients.CountryId, Clients.ClientType, Countries.Country,
BookingAccommodation.AccomId, BookingAccommodation.ShareType, BookingProgram.ProgramId,
Programs.ProgramDesc
    FROM Bookings
    JOIN Clients ON Clients.ClientId = Bookings.ClientId AND Bookings.WeekBeginning >= '2016-10-01' AND Clients.Email <> ''
    JOIN BookingProgram ON Bookings.BookingId = BookingProgram.BookingId
    JOIN BookingAccommodation ON Bookings.BookingId = BookingAccommodation.BookingId AND BookingAccommodation.Nights > 0
    JOIN Countries ON Clients.CountryId = Countries.CountryId
    JOIN Programs ON Programs.ProgramId = BookingProgram.ProgramId
    WHERE Bookings.WeekBeginning >= '2016-10-01';
```

If this is not getting you the results you wanted, try EXPLAIN and see the query plan.

Please Note: I didn't see table ClientType is being used anywhere so I did not include it in JOINs

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is essentially the same query query using JOIN instead of WHERE. I tried it but the performance was the same as before.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than spend more time trying to improve the select statement as it hits so many tables I opted to split it into the separate queries as I outlined in the original question.

In the end this was the quickest practical solution.